# subsetting a dataframe by $

Tags: r, subset

My dataframe is:

```
val1 <- 101:118
degree<-rep(c(1:3), times=6)
id<-rep(c("WT", "KO"), each=9)
df <- data.frame(id, val1, degree)
```

subset the df such that it only contains observations with a degree of 3 which is

```
dfb<-df[c(df$degree==3),]
```

why do I need to combine df$degree==3

By mistake I typed `dfc<-df[c(df$degree),]` and I got this

```
   id val1 degree
1   WT  101      1
2   WT  102      2
3   WT  103      3
1.1 WT  101      1
2.1 WT  102      2
3.1 WT  103      3
1.2 WT  101      1
2.2 WT  102      2
3.2 WT  103      3
1.3 WT  101      1
2.3 WT  102      2
3.3 WT  103      3
1.4 WT  101      1
2.4 WT  102      2
3.4 WT  103      3
1.5 WT  101      1
2.5 WT  102      2
3.5 WT  103      3
```

Can somebody explaining what I am actually subsetting in this WRONG approach?

Comment: You don't need `c` just `df[df$degree==3,]`.  Why you got the output is because `df$degree` has numeric values 1, 2, 3, etc. which acts as row index, so the rows are repeated according to the number

Comment: Because you need to tell R what is `degree`. If you do `df$degree`, R knows `degree` is a column within `df`. In your second approach you are subsetting the indices within `df` according to `df$degree`. Which means selecting 1:3 rows several times.